# Database wrapper like Massive by Rob Conery for SQL Server 2005 and ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2005

Yes I still use the older version of the .NET Framework & love it. Would like to use a database wrapper now [massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) by rob is awesome if I had 3.5 but Nooooo.

- You got any suggestions for a database wrapper ?

Please don't suggest a ORM(ex NHibernate, Active Record) all we do is write stored procedures and supply them parameters in our data access layer. Nothing more nothing less, we are thinking of abstracting away parameters as object now thinking wrapper might be out there or rolling out our own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper dot net - written by Sam Saffron of Stackoverflow fame - is a good alternative to Massive, and it's very similar, but also supports .NET 3.5.

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

But you definitely need to upgrade to at least .NET 3.5 - 2.0 is really really REALLY old by now..... since it still uses the same CLR version (2.0), it shouldn't be any problem anyway - just upgrade - it's not more effort than installing a security update...

The 3.5 support is a bit less "elegant" in some places (like when you need to provide lots of parameters to a method call, since 3.5 doesn't have optional and default parameters yet), but it works like a charm!

It handles stored procedures without any problem - even those that return multiple result sets....

If you **really cannot** upgrade to .NET 3.5 (why is that again??), then the best you can do is the Microsoft [Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648628.aspx) - but that's light years behind the nicety of Massive or Dapper.NET .....

Comment: Upvote for dapper , again i will not be able to use 3.5(`stupid organization policies u know`). God no i will never get to touch `Microsoft Application Block` ever, dreaded Satan in disguise.

Comment: may be you can help with another question too on authentication and authorization over here thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721656/coding-permission-or-operation-based-roles-and-membership-in-asp-net-2-0

Answer (score 1):

How about Microsoft's [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/)? Older versions that will work with 2.0 are still available. I've used this in the past quite effectively (although we have since moved to the Entity Framework in 3.5).